# cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

The guys ran into such a problem that the Interface Get Product Details Repository cannot be provided without a method with an annotation @Provides.
The public abstract static Singleton class implements App_Generated Injector.

Although it worked before, how to solve the problem?

```
interface InterfaceGetProductDetailsRepository {
    suspend fun getDetailsProduct(id:String): Flow<ProductDetail>
}


@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
class DomainModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideGetProducts(mockRepository: MockRepository): GetProductsInterface =
        GetProductsUseCaseImpl(interfaceGetProductsRepository = mockRepository)

    @Provides
    fun provideGetProfile(mockRepository: MockRepository): GetProfile =
        GetProfileUseCaseImpl(interfaceGetProfileRepository = mockRepository)

    @Provides
    fun provideUserAuthorization(mockRepository: MockRepository): UserAuthorization =
        UserAuthorizationUseCaseImpl(interfaceGetLoginRepository = mockRepository)

    @Provides
    fun provideGetProductDetails(mockRepository: MockRepository): GetProductDetailsInterface =
        GetProductDetailsUseCaseImpl(interfaceGetProductDetailsRepository = mockRepository)

    @Provides
    fun provideGetActiveOrders(mockRepository: MockRepository): GetActiveOrderInterface =
        GetActiveOrderImpl(interfaceGetActiveOrdersRepository = mockRepository)

    @Provides
    fun provideGetToken(mockRepository: MockRepository): GetToken =
        GetTokenUseCaseImpl(interfaceGetToken = mockRepository)

    @Provides
    fun provideSaveToken(mockRepository: MockRepository): SaveToken =
        SaveTokenUseCaseImpl(interfaceSaveToken = mockRepository)
}

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class DataModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMockRepository(tokenStorage: TokenStorage): MockRepository =
        MockRepository(tokenStorage)

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideSaveToken(@ApplicationContext context: Context): TokenStorage {
        return SaveToken(context = context)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `InterfaceGetProductDetailsRepository` is not provided anywhere, you should provide it somehow by creating an implementation and then providing it, for example you can create `GetProductDetailsRepositoryImpl` so you can provide it like the following:

```kotlin
@Provides
fun provideGetProductDetailsRepository(mockRepository: MockRepository): InterfaceGetProductDetailsRepository {
     return GetProductDetailsRepositoryImpl(mockRepository)
}
```

Hope this will work

Comment: Provided and used

interface GetProductDetailsInterface {
    suspend fun getDetailsProduct(id: String): Flow<ProductDetail>
}

class GetProductDetailsUseCaseImpl(
    private val interfaceGetProductDetailsRepository: InterfaceGetProductDetailsRepository
) : GetProductDetailsInterface {

    override suspend fun getDetailsProduct(id: String): Flow<ProductDetail> =
        interfaceGetProductDetailsRepository.getDetailsProduct(id)

}